# PHP + MySQL insert not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql-insert

I've been searching for some answers but can't figure out what's happening.

The SQL connection is working perfectly, I've checked it. So I have this POST method.

```
  if(isset($_POST['new_data'])) {
    $new_nm = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_REQUEST['new_name']);
    $new_pstn = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_REQUEST['new_position']);
    ...
        $db->query("INSERT INTO data (name, position, description, twitter, email, image) VALUES('$new_nm', '$new_pstn',
            '$new_dscrpt', '$new_twt', '$new_mail', '$new_img')");
    }
```

And here's the form from where I'm getting the data:

```
<form role="form" method="post">
    <label>Name</label>
        <input name="new_name" class="form-control" />
    <label>Position</label>
        <input name="new_position" class="form-control" />
    ...
    <button type="submit" name="new_data">Submit!</button>
</form>
```

When I click in the button I don't get the data inserted. What am I doing wrong? I have another POST method with a different name which is working (that one makes an UPDATE).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you provide structure of your table?

Comment: Why don't you try adding: *echo "INSERT INTO data (name, position, description, twitter, email, image) VALUES('$new_nm', '$new_pstn',
            '$new_dscrpt', '$new_twt', '$new_mail', '$new_img')";* to see if you get a properly formatted result with the variables filled in.  That usually helps my troubleshoot.

Comment: @Rulisp `id` ENUM('') NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, `name` text NOT NULL, `position` text NOT NULL, `description` text NOT NULL, `twitter` text, `email` varchar(60), `image` varchar(300) NOT NULL

Comment: @Keith just did that and the introduced values are ok! they just not get inserted :(

Comment: Do you have access to phpmyadmin or mysql from the command line.  The next step would be to see what error you're getting back from mysql.  I can usually find my mistake in a few minutes simply by taking my query in plain text (like you just did) and then running the sql directly.

Comment: @kadota I'm not sure, but I think that problem is in your `id` field. Convert it to int and may be add it AUTO_INCREMENT option

Comment: @Rulisp Gotcha! Thanks a lot! I was getting there too thanks to Keith idea of using the command line (which showed an id error), so I'll keep that in mind for the next time. Really appreciated, guys.

Comment: @kadota glad to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'll try to answer this question.

According to table structure, problem is in `id` field, which should be `int` with AUTO_INCREMENT.

Also, I want to make some suggestion for your input

```
if(isset($_POST['new_data'])) 
{
//Always check your input and sanitize it with htmlspecialchars() or htmlentities()
    $new_nm = htmlspecialchars(isset($_REQUEST['new_name']) ? $_REQUEST['new_name'] : "");
    $new_nm = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $new_nm);

    ...
    $db->query("INSERT INTO data (name, position, description, twitter, email, image) VALUES('$new_nm', '$new_pstn',
            '$new_dscrpt', '$new_twt', '$new_mail', '$new_img')");
}
```